# featuretools generated null columns while there should be values

Tags: python, data-science, data-cleaning, feature-engineering, featuretools

#### Background:

In using the automated feature engineering library featuretools, I first built 2 datasets `member` and `order` in the entityset. I build a relationship between them by implying `ft.Relationship(es['member']['memberId'], es['order'][memberId'])`. Thus the entityset looks like that:

```
Entityset: featuretoolsTesting01
  Entities:
    member [Rows: 60115, Columns: 6]
    order [Rows: 600, Columns: 7]
  Relationships:
    order.memberId -> member.memberId
```

We can see that 60k members have 600 order records (7 columns with nearly no null value) and I want to generate some features like MODE(order.amount), so I implement the dfs:

```
feature_matrix, feature_names = ft.dfs(entityset=es, target_entity='member',
                                       n_jobs = 4, verbose = 1, features_only = False,
                                       max_depth = 1)
```

After the dfs I did have found some columns like `'SUM(orders_es.spu_kind)', 'SUM(orders_es.spu_quantity)', 'STD(orders_es.spu_kind)', 'COUNT(orders_es)', 'NUM_UNIQUE(orders_es.source)', 'MODE(orders_es.source)' ......`

#### Issue:

But I found surprisingly that all these columns are null (all NaN) and no single value >0.
All the `len(feature_matrix[feature_matrix[i] > 0])` is 0.

What's the problem? I still recalled that a few months earlier when doing a similar featuretools to generate a bunch of features I can have a good feature_matrix table, then why this time the order-related columns are all null?

Answer (score 2):

Opps I found out where the problem is: it turns out to be the mismatch between the index of `order` and the index of `member`, they did have been transformed to `string` format, but transforming `int` or `float` to `string` leads to no match.
After using `member.memberId.astype('int').astype('str')` and the coop

Comment: Sorry for the 'stupid' question here, some might meet a similar situation and might also find the 'astype' method to be useful though...